# Questions regarding laws on technology designed to avoid prosecution?

Tags: criminal-law, australia, commerce, product-liability

From my understanding it is illegal to operate a car with a radar detector installed in all states of Australia, but.

- Is it illegal to posses one if it's not being used?
- Would there be anything in Australian law that prevented an Australian company from manufacturing them?
- What if the products were for export to international markets where they were legal?
- Is there a crime involved with designing a piece of technology that would aid the consumer to avoid detection and or prosecution for an offence?
- What if secondary non illegal use cases could be argued?

Answer (score 1):

It’s not illegal to use one in Western Australia. It’s not illegal to have or make one anywhere in Australia.